# Laravel looping through dates and insert data to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am looping through 3 cinemas id's and for each one I want to loop for 7 days.

At this moment it is looping through 3 cinemas for today only and also it updates current record so if a cinema is playing film "Wonder Woman" and another cinemas plays the same film, it will merge the times together and that is not what I want.

Each cinema should be associated to business_id and therefore each cinema should have it's own record, even if the name matches.

> $films = Business::where('type', $type)->get();

Is giving me back 3 records like this:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"hello","type":"3","email":"fsdf","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":3,"name":"dasd","type":"3","email":"fsdfsdf","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":4,"name":"dasdas","type":"3","email":"dasdasd","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

My array that I loop through has 3 entries:

```
$arrayOfCinemaIds = [10565,7311,9434];
```

So I want to match it so that first entry in array matches first entry from where::

I also want it to insert a new entry when date changes not overwrite it currently I have something like:

[image]

Taking "Wonder Woman" as example again what I want is something like this:

```
id=5
title=Wonder Women
times=times
date=today (so 14-06-2017)
business_id = 4

id=6
title=Wonder Women
times=times
date=tomorrow (so 15-06-2017)
business_id = 4

id=
title=Wonder Women
times=times
date=today (so 14-06-2017)
business_id = 3
```

My code so far:

```
function odeon(){
    $arrayOfCinemaIds = [10565,7311,9434];
    $startdate = strtotime("today");
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $startdate);
    $enddate = strtotime("+7 Days");
    $type = 3;
    $business_id = 1;
    $films = Business::where('type', $type)->get();
    //echo $films;
    while ($startdate < $enddate) {
        foreach($arrayOfCinemaIds as $id){
        $business_id = $business_id + 1;
    //append your id
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/'.$id.'/?day='.$date);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $id = 1;
    foreach($data->listings as $listing){
      $title = $listing->title;
      $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);
      $film = Film::where('id', $id)->first();
      $id = $id + 1;
      // if news is null
      if (!$film) {
        $film = new Film();
      }
      $film->title = $title;
      $film->times = $time;
      $film->business_id = $business_id;
      $film->date = $date;
      $film->save();
      $startdate = strtotime("+1 Days", $startdate);
    }
        }
}
```

### Edit

I have managed to get it like this:

```
function odeon(){
    $arrayOfCinemaIds = [10565,7311,9434];
    $startdate = strtotime("today");
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $startdate);
    $enddate = strtotime("+7 Days");
    $type = 3;
    while ($startdate < $enddate) {
        foreach($arrayOfCinemaIds as $id){
    //append your id
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/'.$id.'/?day='.$date);;
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $film_id = 1;
    $films = Business::where('type', $type)->get();
        foreach ($films as $film) {
            $business_id =  $film->id;
        foreach($data->listings as $listing){
            $title = $listing->title;
            $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);
            $film = Film::where('id', $id)->first();
            $film_id = $film_id + 1;
      if (!$film) {
        $film = new Film();
      }
      $film->title = $title;
      $film->times = $time;
      $film->business_id = $business_id;
      $film->date = $date;
      $film->save();
            }
        }
      $startdate = strtotime("+1 Days", $startdate);
      $date = date("Y-m-d", $startdate);
    }
}
```

However it is running throught only 1 cinema so cinema with id '10565' and not the others

Answer (score 0):

Change this `$film->date = $date;` to `$film->date = $startdate;` this statement will give updated date and save.

Comment: date does change unfortunately it only loops throught 1 cinema id so [10565] instead of all 3?

Answer (score 0):

Cut `while ($startdate < $enddate) {` line and paste it after `foreach ($data->listings as $listing) {` and add one line before `foreach ($data->listings as $listing) {` this line  `$startdate = $date;`. check below code if you don't understand.

```
function odeon() {
    $arrayOfCinemaIds = [10565, 7311, 9434];
    $startdate = strtotime("today");
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $startdate);
    $enddate = strtotime("+7 Days");
    $type = 3;
    $business_id = 1;
    $films = Business::where('type', $type)->get();
    //echo $films;

    foreach ($arrayOfCinemaIds as $id) {
        $business_id = $business_id + 1;
        //append your id
        $data = file_get_contents('https://api.cinelist.co.uk/get/times/cinema/' . $id . '/?day=' . $date);
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $id = 1;
        $startdate = $date;
        foreach ($data->listings as $listing) {
            while ($startdate < $enddate) {
                $title = $listing->title;
                $time = implode(', ', $listing->times);
                $film = Film::where('id', $id)->first();
                $id = $id + 1;
                // if news is null
                if (!$film) {
                    $film = new Film();
                }
                $film->title = $title;
                $film->times = $time;
                $film->business_id = $business_id;
                $film->date = $startdate;
                $film->save();
                $startdate = strtotime("+1 Days", $startdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that I get infinite loop with same record all the time

Comment: `while ($startdate < $enddate) {` here we have put condition, that will prevent infinite loop and here `$startdate = strtotime("+1 Days", $startdate);` we are adding a single day each time.

Comment: unfortunately it only gives me output for 1 item in array not all of them

Comment: add this line `$id = $id + 1;` below `foreach ($arrayOfCinemaIds as $id) {` loop and remove from `while ($startdate < $enddate) {` loop, below this `$film = Film::where('id', $id)->first();` line of code